# Execute two INSERT statements

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

I have two seperate INSERT statements that I want to run one after the other,
the first one runs successfully but it seems like it isn't even getting to the second statement any idea why?

```vbnet
Try
    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    resultSQL.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Green
    resultSQL.Text = "Successfully Saved"

Catch ex As Exception
    Response.Write(ex.Message)
    resultSQL.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
    resultSQL.Text = ex.Message

Finally

End Try
```

INSERT 2 which is not running:

```
strQuery = "INSERT INTO [SD_EPOS_Entry]" _
    & " ([Trade_Activity_Code] " _
    & " VALUES " _
    & " (@Trade_Activity_Code1)"

cmd = New SqlCommand(strQuery)

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Trade_Activity_Code1", tcodeVar)

Try

    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    resultSQL.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Green
    resultSQL.Text = "Successfully Saved2"

Catch ex As Exception

    Response.Write(ex.Message)
    resultSQL.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
    resultSQL.Text = ex.Message

Finally
```

Comment: Isn't `con` already open since you haven't closed it in the previous insert? Are you getting an error at that part?

Comment: @shree.pat18 good point! i will correct this, no error generated

Comment: Can you please show the entire method?

Comment: Why do you even use two commands for this? Why not a single one making two inserts?

Comment: @Crono How would I do this with the parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right off the bat there seems to be a missing parenthesis in your second query:

```
strQuery = "INSERT INTO [SD_EPOS_Entry]" _
        & " ([Trade_Activity_Code] " _
        & " VALUES " _
        & " (@Trade_Activity_Code1)"
```

It should be:

```
strQuery = "INSERT INTO [SD_EPOS_Entry]" _
        & " ([Trade_Activity_Code]) " _
        & " VALUES " _
        & " (@Trade_Activity_Code1)"
```

I would also advise for proper disposal of any `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection` instances you create, either by using the `Dispose()` method or declaring them in a `Using` statement.

If as you say your second query isn't even reached, follow your code at runtime with a debugger and look at which point it stops. That ougth to provide some clue.

**UPDATE:**

This should execute both your INSERT statements in a single operation:

```
strQuery = "INSERT INTO [SD_T_Code]" _
    & " ([Trade_Activity_Code]) " _
    & " VALUES " _
    & " (@Trade_Activity_Code)" _
    & ";INSERT INTO [SD_EPOS_Entry]" _
    & " ([Trade_Activity_Code]) " _
    & " VALUES " _
    & " (@Trade_Activity_Code)"

Dim strMessage As String = "Successfully saved"
Dim resultColor As Drawing.Color = Drawing.Color.Green

Using cmd = New SqlCommand(strQuery, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Trade_Activity_Code", tcodeVar)

    Try
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        resultSQL.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Green
        resultSQL.Text = "Successfully Saved"
    Catch ex As SqlException
        strMessage = ex.Message
        resultColor = Drawing.Color.Red
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
End Using

// Write results outside of db operation
Response.Write(strMessage)
resultSQL.ForeColor = resultColor
resultSQL.Text = strMessage
```

Of course the above assumes there's an instanciated, unopen con connection variable present.

Notice that it also only catches `SqlException`. Catching the basic `Exception` here seems wrong to me.

**SECOND UPDATE:**

If the above code isn't working, the issue may be caused by an Sql Trigger.

Comment: thanks for your reply, thats probably due to me cutting down the insert query just for the examples sake, each insert works fine by themselves

Comment: thanks again, are you missing a `_` on the first `Values Trade_Activity_Code` line or is that intentional?

Comment: @neeko That wasn't intentional. Edited.

Comment: @neeko just edited again. Would be best if `Response.Write` wasn't called while connection is still open.

Comment: thanks for your help, but this doesn't work either, first one executes fine, the second one doesn't both insert in SQL Server

Comment: @neeko and yet you don't have any exception messages? Then the problem might be related to a Sql Trigger. Make sure the targetted tables doesn't have any. If they do, check what's going on in them.

Comment: no sql trigger, If i assign the 2 insert statement to its own sub that runs when another button clicks it inserts perfectly, just not together :/

Comment: @neeko Have you tried tracing the queries sent with Sql Server Profiler? Make sure the query is sent and that nothing else comes thereafter to delete your records. Pass this point I'm afraid I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere not shown in your code, you are assigning the connection to the command object (this is for the first query).

When you get to the second query, you're redefining the cmd object as a new object, which is also removing any reference to the connection as established earlier.

Try this for your second block of code:

```
strQuery = "INSERT INTO [SD_EPOS_Entry]" _
    & " ([Trade_Activity_Code] " _
    & " VALUES " _
    & " (@Trade_Activity_Code1)"

cmd = New SqlCommand(strQuery, cnn) 'Define the connection to be used for the command.
```